# Why can't I insert a row in my table

Tags: birt

This is driving me crazy! In the BIRT Report Designer (Eclipse), no matter what I do, Insert -> Row -> Above/Below is always grayed out. I know I've done it in other reports, but this report won't work. Is there something special I need to know?

I select the row, right-click, then select Insert. Nothing.

It might be worth noting that I can't Delete the table either.

Comment: Can you paste the XML of the table? The easiest way of getting it (imo) is selecting the table, then clicking the 'XML source' tab. It should select the first tag of the table.

Also, which version of Eclipse and Birt are you using? You can see this by selecting Help -> about Eclipse for the Eclipse version, and then clicking the icon for the BIRT project (which looks like an ordinary Eclipse icon, unfortunately) for the BIRT version.

Comment: You want me to paste the entire XML, or just the table XML? I'm using BIRT 4.3 and Eclipse Juno.

Comment: @user1660256, have you though about deleting this question?  Given your solution, it does not add anything to SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply restarted Eclipse and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are selecting the table element.  Right click on the area in dark blue in the image below (it turns dark when selected).

[image]

Comment: The entire row absolutely turns blue. I right-click, hit Insert, Row, but Above and Below are still grayed out.

Comment: P.S. - I'm not able to Merge Cells either. It's like the whole table is "locked" or something. Nor can I delete the table to itself to try to start over.